# Inishtech / Software Potential Code Protector integration with Visual Studio build or Setup project

Tags: asp.net, .net, source-code-protection

Have anyone tried InishTech [Software Potential Code Protector](http://www.inishtech.com/code-protector/) ?

Can we integrate this with our build programmatically? I found tutorials but those were to do with the help of the Code Protector standalone GUI. What I want to know is do they have an SDK  so that we can integrate with our code or some perfect tutorial which can opt-out dependencies from our setup.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: There's been a [Getting Started guide that covers code Protection](http://docs.softwarepotential.com/Getting-Started-With-Code-Protection.html) added since I wrote the answer. (Exec summary: You add 2 NuGet packages and then put attributes on what you want to protect and protection is automatically integrated into the build process, be that from within Visual Studio or on a Build Server. Key simplifications are that you no longer need to add a `SLPS_PROTECT` Symbol or install an SDK anywhere.)

---

You can use the automatic Protection during building as detailed in the [relevant KB article](http://www.inishtech.com/KB12).

This hooks in an MSBuild-based build extension which will feed each assembly EXE/DLL as you compile it into the [Command-Line Code Protector](http://www.inishtech.com/KB2) when you #define `SLPS_PROTECT` in **Project| settings|Build tab|General area|Conditional compilation symbols** (you might only want to do this for the *Release* configuration).

The Protected code then continues on its way, e.g., into your Setup Project or WebDeploy package.

Typically when using this approach, you [declaratively mark the Feature to be associated with each Protected Method](http://www.inishtech.com/KB13) using the `[Feature]` attribute:-

```
[Feature]
void ProtectedCode()
{
    ...
}
```

You may also find further relevant details in the [knowledgebase](http://www.inishtech.com/Support/Knowledge-Base.aspx), [FAQs](http://www.inishtech.com/Support/FAQs.aspx) and in the [forum](http://www.inishtech.com/Support/Forum.aspx).

UPDATE: There's a new http://docs.softwarepotential.com/ which provides more focused getting started guides than there were at the time I answered the question. There are also a set of samples up at: https://github.com/SoftwarePotential/samples including installer-related ones.

Any further questions, please feel free to ask - either here or on the [forum](http://www.inishtech.com/Support/Forum.aspx).

Disclaimer: I work for InishTech.

Comment: one thing i have to ask... whenever i tried registering a free account for testing.they always give me a key but when i enter that  temprary key to create  temprary account JUST FOR TESTING  they say that  this key is invalid.. this is confusing..  means if that key is  invalid then which key i have to use to create trial account on inishtech :S :S

Comment: they gave me this key when i tried  a minute ago 29ZXY-U4Y8H-8XJHH-R2UCL-TXMFA but still  saying that key is invalid

Comment: @Farooq May be worth dealing with that through support - Any email can only be used for one trial period hence you may need to use a new address and/or get your trial extended? Support should be able to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Code Protector is fantastic product from InishTech
I am using this for my startup and it works great and do it's job extensively well
just go for it